# How to properly prevent bubbling when using toggle()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-bubbling

I am trying to show the lists on page load if more than 768px but hide them if less and make them show on clicking the titles.

It works OK but not after resizing the window and I don't get why is this happening? Any advice?

How should I handle the bubbling properly?

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <h3 class="nav__title">first</h3>
    <div class="links">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">first one</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">first two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">first three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<nav>
    <h3 class="nav__title">second</h3>
    <div class="links">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">second one</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">second two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">second three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

JS:

```
(function () {

    function footerLinks() {
        if ($(window).width() < 768) {
            $(".links").hide();
            $(".nav__title").on("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).next(".links").toggle("fast");
            });
        } else {
            $(".links").show();
        }
    }

    footerLinks();

    $(window).resize(function () {
        footerLinks();
    });

}());
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/carlozdre/E64j4/3/)

Comment: Responsive CSS will solve your purpose ....

Comment: @CeeAim So, you should answer that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want, you were adding up event handlers every time the window was resized:

```
(function () {

     $(".nav__title").on("click", function (e) {

                e.preventDefault();

                // Drop out of function if window is big enough
                if( $(window).width() >= 768 ){ return; }

                $(this).next(".links").toggle("fast");
            });

    function footerLinks() {

        if ($(window).width() < 768) {         

            $(".links").hide();

        } else { 
            $(".links").show(); 
        }            
    }

    footerLinks();

    $(window).resize(function () {
        footerLinks();
    });

 }());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E64j4/6/

Comment: the reason I've done it like that is because I want the titles only to expand the lists if less than 768px, and if I get the onclick event in the if where I am checking the windows width, I get the bubbling issue; how should I go about this? wrapping the click event in the same conditional doesn't really work

Comment: There are different ways to do it, but see my changes above. You could have also unbound events, but I think this is a more readable & maintainable way. A 3rd solution would have been with CSS classes and media queries.